# Nothing shown in in the view.html page

Tags: django

The view login.views.IndexView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

```
class IndexView(FormView):
    form_class = NameForm
    template_name = 'reg.html'
    success_url='display'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

class DisplayView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'view.html'
    def dis(self,request):
        st4=[]
        st5=[]
        ob=Register.objects.all()
        for i in ob:
            st4.append(i.name)
            st5.append(i.rollno)
        return render(request,'view.html',{'st4':st4,'st5':st5})
```

Comment: Note that there isn't anything in your view that will ever call your `dis` method. I'm not sure what you expect that to do.

Comment: i have edited the code.now nothing shows in the view page

Comment: As I said before, that's because you've written a `dis` method but there is no code that will ever call it. I've explained in more detail in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `form_valid` method should return a response. For a `FormView`, the easiest thing to do would be to call `super()` and return that.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.save()
    return super(IndexView, self).form_valid(form)
```

In your `DisplayView`, you've written a `dis` method but you haven't written any code that will actually call it. The simplest thing to do would to use a function-based-view instead.

```
def dis(request):
    st4=[]
    st5=[]
    ob=Register.objects.all()
    for i in ob:
        st4.append(i.name)
        st5.append(i.rollno)
    return render(request,'view.html',{'st4':st4,'st5':st5})
```

Then change your url pattern to use `views.dis` instead of `views.DisplayView.as_view()`.

If you really want to use `TemplateView`, then you could override `get_context_data` and add `st4` and `st5` to the context there.

```
class DisplayView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'view.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DisplayView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        st4=[]
        st5=[]
        ob=Register.objects.all()
        for i in ob:
            st4.append(i.name)
            st5.append(i.rollno)
        context['st4'] = st4
        context['st5'] = st5
        return context
```

Unless you're familiar with class-based-views, the function-based view is easier to understand so I would stick with that. The `TemplateView` is not automatically better than the function based view.

Comment: The error solved.but now it shows nothing in view.hrml page

Comment: error showing "get_context_data() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"

Comment: You're missing the `self` in `def get_context_data`.

Comment: now the problem is solved.I used the method dis() without class

Comment: can you explain what happens when using the  calss based -context_data

Comment: I’m not sure what you want explained. [This page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context) from the docs might help.

Answer (score 0):

```
class IndexView(FormView):
    form_class = NameForm
    template_name = 'reg.html'
    success_url='display'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

def dis(request):
    st4=[]
    st5=[]
    ob=Register.objects.all()
    for i in ob:
        st4.append(i.name)
        st5.append(i.rollno)
    return render(request,'view.html',{'st4':st4,'st5':st5})
```